# JPA-Hibernate With Hibernate Interceptor

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I try to do AuditLog with this example [link](http://jaketrent.com/post/audit-history-hibernate-interceptor/) without Spring. I used  JPA. I tried to annotate EntityManager but it didn't work.I tried to debug and `em` in `MyUtil` was null. Can you help me to get that session? I saw many people using hibernate session but if I want to use `EntityManager` what should I do?
My sample code:

```
public class serviceBean {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPC")
EntityManager em; //not null

public insert(entity en) {
     em.merge(en)
}

public class demoLog extends EmptyInterceptor {

public void doSave(){
     MyUtil.logIt(entityLog);
}
}

public class MyUtil {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPC")
EntityManager em; // got null here

public static void logIt(EntityLog entity) {
     em.merge(entity);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have no container managed entity manager (you mentioned "without Spring") then it's rather straightforward.

Note that I think you have to use different persistency unit for the audit log interceptor to prevent infinite loop (PU_2 in my example).

So you need persistence.xml in META-INF (for holding db connections settings and JPA / Hibernate properties):

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="PU_1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <description>Can be anything</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>pack.entities.Test</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db01;create=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="APP" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="anything" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

            <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="pack.AuditInterceptor" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="PU_2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <description>For DB audit log</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>pack.entities.AuditLog</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db01;create=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="APP" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="anything" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And you should programatically create your EntityManagerFactory and EntityManager like this in your main program:

```
package pack;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import pack.entities.Test;

public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PU_1");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setName("something for name");
        em.persist(t);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        t = new Test();
        t.setName("something for name 2");
        em.persist(t);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

And like this in your audit log hibernate interceptor:

```
package pack;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;

import pack.entities.AuditLog;

public class AuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private EntityManager em;

    public AuditInterceptor() {
        System.out.println("AuditInterceptor constructed");
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PU_2");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        System.out.println("onSave called");
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        AuditLog a = new AuditLog();
        a.setEntry("object with ID: " + id + " saved");
        em.persist(a);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTransactionCompletion(Transaction tx) {
        System.out.println("afterTransactionCompletion called");
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        AuditLog a = new AuditLog();
        a.setEntry("transaction: " + tx + " completed");
        em.persist(a);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

The entity classes:

```
package pack.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

package pack.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class AuditLog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String entry;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEntry() {
        return entry;
    }

    public void setEntry(String entry) {
        this.entry = entry;
    }

}
```